# Excel VBA not breaking properly

Tags: excel, vba, case

I'm newer to Excel VBA but I'm using it for a certification tracker that measures belt status. The requirements have changed frequently but I'm having trouble with it not stopping at the right place.

The requirements are that you need 10 requirements for a white belt, once you've completed that you need those 10 + 8 for an orange belt. The code currently checks white for the requirements and then will check orange to give a % to the next belt.

If all the orange is complete it is showing as an orange belt and skipping the previously reviewed white belt requirements (giving orange belt if all 8 things are completed but even if only 9 of the 10 white are complete). Can I add anything to the sub below to stop this?

```
Private Sub CheckForBeltStatus_Core(currentRow As Integer, rangeAll As Range, whiteRange As Range, orangeRange As Range, greenRange As Range, blackRange As Range, myCurrentRow As Integer)

    Dim currentRange As Range
    Dim cReps As New Collection
    Dim currentbelt As String, coreBelt As String

    j = currentRow

    For x = 1 To 4
        Select Case x
        Case 1
            Set currentRange = whiteRange
            columnCount = 10
            beltLevel = "White"
        Case 2
            Set currentRange = orangeRange
            columnCount = 8
            beltLevel = "Orange"
        Case 3
            Set currentRange = greenRange
            columnCount = 4
            beltLevel = "Green"
        Case 4
            Set currentRange = blackRange
            columnCount = 2
            beltLevel = "Black"
        End Select

        For k = 1 To currentRange.Columns.Count
            If currentRange(j, k) <> "" Then
                currentCount = currentCount + 1
            End If
        Next

        Select Case x
        Case 1
            loadedWhiteTotal = currentCount
        Case 2
            loadedOrangeTotal = currentCount
        Case 3
            loadedGreenTotal = currentCount
        Case 4
            loadedBlackTotal = currentCount
        End Select

        If currentCount <= columnCount Then
            Select Case beltLevel
            Case "Green"
                Call CheckGroups(myCurrentRow)
            Case "Black"
                Call CheckGroups(myCurrentRow)
            End Select

            If BeltBuilder(beltLevel) = True Then loadedMyBelt = beltLevel
        End If

        currentCount = 0
    Next

    If loadedMyBelt = "" Then loadedMyBelt = "No Belt Achieved"

End Sub
```

Comment: The code is simple enough but I'm having a hard time understanding your explanation.

Comment: I might not be showing it correctly but basically, if they don't have the required column count for case 1 (say 9 of the 10 required columns) but do have all required for case 2 (8 columns) it's showing they are Case 2 ("Orange") but should have stopped checking when all of Case 1 wasn't satisfied.

Comment: Oh, then it sounds like you should be replacing your `select case` logic with `if` logic because select statements keep moving down until they find a case that fits.